# Can I read the transform matrix of an applied SCNConstraint?

Tags: 3d, scenekit

I have applied an `SCNBillboardConstraint` to a node in my SceneKit scene. It works fine and the node orients itself towards the `pointOfView`.

Now I'd like to access the implicit transform matrix set by the constraint.

I need this to calculate the orientation of other sibling nodes that should be dependent of the orientation of my constraint node.

However, when I read the `transform` `orientation` or `eulerAngles` properties, they're all at their default and don't reflect the current "billboarded"  orientation. The `convertPosition(_:from:)` API also seems to ignore the orientation set by the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced exactly the same problem. The solution for me was to look at the node's presentation object and read the transform matrix from there:

```
node.presentation.transform
```